# Firebase ios manage download with FirebaseUI

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui, swift4.1

If I use `FirebaseUI` to download images, can we manage(pause, stop or resume) downloads. And also if I need progress, can I get the progress? My main problem is, is there a way to manage downlaods as tasks with using `FirebaseUI`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files ? It has examples on how to manage the download and even get the progress, using FirebaseUI.

> Manage Downloads
>   In addition to starting downloads, you can pause, resume, and cancel downloads using the pause, resume, and cancel methods. These methods raise pause, resume, and cancel events that you can observe.

```
// Start downloading a file
let downloadTask = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg").write(toFile: localFile)

// Pause the download
downloadTask.pause()

// Resume the download
downloadTask.resume()

// Cancel the download
downloadTask.cancel()
```

> Monitor Download Progress
>   You can attach observers to FIRStorageDownloadTasks in order to monitor the progress of the download. Adding an observer returns a FIRStorageHandle that can be used to remove the observer.

```
// Add a progress observer to a download task
let observer = downloadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
  // A progress event occurred
}
```

Comment: In FirebaseUI no need to create task. Just put the reference and set image to imageview.